# Record counts of a Journey don't match with Reports

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I'm having an issue I mentioned in the title.

For example, when I create a DE for a campaign (journey), let's say I have 100 people to send an email to. But when I look at the Journey reports, I can only see that 60 people received it. Of course there are some soft/hard errors but let's say they're 20. So, what happens to the rest, 20 people?

Looking forward to your answers. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple reasons as to why this is happening.

- **Delay in the Reports**: From my experience, sometimes they can be a delay in the counts of sends vs the counts in your email. This is because the reports are fetching the data from data views and it might take some time to reflect there.
- **Unsubscribes**: Your question does not mention anything related to unsubscribes. Some subscribers might be unsubscribed in 'All Subscribers' List and will not be sent the email(Assuming this is a commercial email). A good way would be to check the status of the subscribers in your DE against the `_Subscribers` Data view.
- **List Detective Feature in Salesforce**: Salesforce internally maintains a list of email addresses that are not sent to. The list typically includes emails in the format of '@info'. You can read more about them [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=000335444&type=1)

If you wish to give a shot on who these customers are exactly that are not sent to from your journey, then you try the below:

**Tracking Extract**: You can set up a tracking extract in Automation Studio. There is an extract type '[Not Sent](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=sf.mc_as_notsent.htm&type=5)', which can give you this information. However, tracking extracts sometimes don't give the best view and there is limited help and support on them.

Comment: I understand. The first and third answers actually satisfied me a bit. I'll look into that. Thank you for your feedback! I'll let the community know if these steps solve my problem :)